# Checking Email exists via Proxy

Tags: php

I've got some code that checks a mailserver for an existence of an email address.

I use something like this to open the connection directly.

```
fsock = @fsockopen($mxhost, 25, $errno, $error, $this->con_timeout)
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to do the process via a socks proxy with username and password.

Can anyone help me out?

---

Lets be more concise:

```
$proxy = "1.2.3.4"; // proxy 
$port = 8080; // proxy port

$fp = fsockopen($proxy,$port); // connect to proxy
fputs($fp, "CONNECT $mailserver:25 ......");
```

I'm not sure what the fputs syntax should be.

Thanks

Comment: Googling `fsockopen proxy` seems to give good results

Comment: did that already lol, but am stumped on what syntax to provide for fputs.  I've updated my answer with more info.

Comment: fputs() is an alias to [`fwrite()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) which requires a handle (your `$fp`) and a string (which will be written in the `$fp`). According to your example, you are trying to open whatever file `1.2.3.4:8080` returns and is trying to write on it `"CONNECT $mailserver:25 ......"`. Is really that you want?

Comment: I don't know what the correct way in doing a proxy connection to a mailserver.  Unless I provide some information I get the comment which is totally useless above lol.  I throw up that code in order to provide some basic info to whoever reads the question.  All I need is a basic HELO, MAIL FROM and RCPT TO just to get things started.

Comment: @PaulM As Brad answer said, not all servers (is there any at all?) that will give you that info so easily. You could try send an empty e-mail to the person and see if any reply message from server about delivery fail shows up. But of course, that would be bad because you need a server response (which will not be instantly) and if e-mail is valid, you are asking yourself to be flagged as spam :D

Comment: Well respectfully Brad is wrong.  It looks like im not going to get anywhere with the current line of questioning.  I'll update my question.

Comment: @PaulM, Right... except that I'm not.  Sure, if you don't care about any decent high level of accuracy, you can do what you're doing.  Perhaps you should update your question, including the statement that you aren't concerned with accuracy.

Comment: I do care about accuracy.  I'll do some more investigation myself and then comeback.  This question is derailing into a direction which isnt helpful to me.

Comment: @PaulM, Perhaps you should change your question to, "How can I write a SOCKS5 client in PHP"

Comment: Funny, you deleted your answer.  now you post this?  lol.